# Execute SSIS SQL Task based on condition

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

Here I've two sql task namely TotalCount_Quest_HF and TotalCount_Quest_HF_Table. These 2 sql task would return total count from 2 tables into variable 'v_TotalCount_Quest_HF' and 'v_TotalCount_Quest_HF_Table'.

Now I want execute 'Preparation SQL Task 1' SQL Task if v_TotalCount_Quest_HF >= v_TotalCount_Quest_HF_Table else stop whole process. How to do this in SSIS ?

[image]

Comment: You can use a conditional split task to check on a condition. If it would not hit and there's no condition path that'll return true your package will end it's run. Although, in a second condition you could add some sort of logging of course.

Comment: You can do all of this inside one execute SQL Task. If you still want ti di it this way, then double click the green arrow and set a condition inside there.

Comment: I found a way to do this by setting constraints and expression to Precedence Constraints.

Answer (score 0):

simply drag a precedence constraint between TotalCount_Quest_HF_Table and Preparation SQL Task 1, and double click that precedence constraint, change from **constraint** to **expression**, and specify your condition in the expression filed by typing directly in the blank field, but in your case, better specify in the window after you click **...**

Answer (score -1):

I found a way to do this by setting constraints and expression to Precedence Constraints. Topic closed